# Sort table so that one columns equals another

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table with two columns which, by design, I know have the same values (here, `colA` and `colB`) but not in the same order. One of those is in the order I want (here, `colA`). I want to order my whole table, except this column (`colA`), so that another column (here, `colB`) is in the order of the column in the right order (`colA`).

Example:

```
colA  colB  colC
5     3     is
7     5     hello
3     7     this
4     4     dog
```

Desired result:

```
colA  colB  colC
5     5     hello
7     7     this
3     3     is
4     4     dog
```

(Notice that the values in `colC` (and other columns) follow those in `colB`) (each value in `colA` and `colB` is unique). Doing this in google sheets.

Comment: Show what you have tried so we may best assist you here

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A4, B1:C4, {1, 2}, 0)))
```

[image]

or see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/126631/186471

Answer (score -1):

Insert another column before A and give them a index starting at 1... 1,2,3,4... This will be used to do a final sort... Now all the columns are named differently then your example so take that into account when reading the below...

```
colA  colB  colC  colD
1     5     3     is
2     7     5     hello
3     3     7     this
4     4     4     dog
```

Next sort  colC and colD (and any other cols) in order of colC. Sort colA and colB in order of colB. Now the numbers in colB and ColC should match. Finally sort all by colA. Delete colA